# LDAP implementation in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I want to implement the LDAP in my MVC web Application.I dont have any knowledge about this.I just know for the time being that this is used for User Authentication using Windows domain Active Directory UserID and Password.
So please suggest me for this to implement this step by step.

Answer (score 0):

If you build an Intranet site that will be hosted within your corporate network, you can use Integrated Windows Authentication which does not require to enter UserID and Password. Please see [detailed tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/216/Windows-Authentication-With-ASP.NET-Web-Pages) regarding this topic.

If you need to use Forms Authentication (user should enter his name and password) then see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).